# formatting JSON response into a table when its ArrayOfString

Tags: jquery, json

Here is a JSON response I have:

```
<ArrayOfstring xmlns:i="protocol://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="protocol://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays">
<string>{</string>
<string> "PersonIdentifier" : "65535",</string>
<string> "Forename" : "Fred",</string>
<string> "Surname" : "Citroen",</string>
<string> "DateOfBirth" : "1987-05-18",</string>
<string> "GenderCode" : "M",</string>
<string> "Version" : "87871705",</string>
<string> "Table" : "PERSONS",</string>
<string> "Column" : "rowid",</string>
<string> "Value" : "AAAYChAAFAAACApAAN",</string>
<string> "CurrentDateTime" : "20180911 111101.693"</string>
<string>}</string>
</ArrayOfstring>
```

I need to format it into a table which is predefined as below:

```
<table id="tableSK">
  <tr>
    <th>Forename</th>
    <th>Surname</th>
    <th>DateOfBirth</th>
    <th>Gender</th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

If I use below JQuery:

```
 $('#tableSK').append('<tr/>');
                 $.each(response, function(i, field){
                $('#tableSK').find('tr:last').append('<td>' + field + '</td>');    
                });
```

I get below output:

[Click to see the output as an image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EJDYO.png)

So essentially, I need to pick strings from that output but specific named properties and not everything.

Can someone guide me to the correct JQuery please.

Comment: That's the weirdest response I've ever seen. It's JSON that's been turned in to XML line-by-line. Why anyone would do that I don't know, but I would strongly suggest you make your first job fixing it. Use one format or the other properly.

Comment: Hi Rory, I agree 100%, unfortunately the web service is not something I work on or have control of, been tasked to call it and use it, sorry :-(

Comment: That response is unuseable. Sure, you could hack together some code to loop through the XML, build the JSON string then deserialise that, but it's an absolute waste of time. The proper solution is to fix the response.

Comment: I have tried but already other client apps running in production with that interface so don't think I will be able to sell a change to service interface, technically yes  but not in the current set of circumstances.

Comment: @SukeshKhare If there are already multiple apps calling this api, then your company/team surely has a library already done that parses this response to a rational format? If not, there should be. Coding the same feature to all of the programs separately just adds to the injury...

Comment: Agreed, this is not JSON at all. But if it's being used widely already, someone will have solved the "how to parse it" problem already. Even if there's no implementation of it using JavaScript, at least there should be an algorithm knocking about. This is a crazy hybrid format though. Why do people invent their own formats when well-defined existing ones are already good the the job and have ready-made parsing tools available. I will never understand.